# Remove Layers in a forEach with condition in openLayer3

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I need to remove some specific Layers of my map, depending on a condition, like:

```
map.getLayers().forEach(function(layer) {
    if (layer.get('title')) {
        map.removeLayer(layer);
    }
});
```

But this doesn't delete all the Layers that get this condition, because the layer collection is modified while looping...

Is there any pattern to answer this problem?
I was thinking about reverse looping to delete the layers but I wasn't able to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reverse looping is the only way I guess, although I agree it is not good that your snippet does not work out of the box. You can reverse loop by accessing the layers array:

```
var layers = map.getLayers().getArray();
for (var i = layers.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
  var layer = layers[i];
  if (layer.get('title')) {
    map.removeLayer(layer);
  }
}
```